# SDO_NN the second nearest neighbor

Tags: oracle-11g, spatial

Oracle SQL geometry allows me to find the nearest neighbor using

```
SDO_NN(neighbors.GEOLOC,p.GEOLOC,'SDO_NUM_RES=1 UNIT = MILE',1) = 'TRUE')
```

How can I get the select the second nearest point?

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_nn.htm#SPATL1032)

> `sdo_num_res` Specifies the number of results (nearest neighbors) to be returned. If neither `sdo_batch_size` nor `sdo_num_res` is specified, this is equivalent to specifying `sdo_batch_size=0`. See the [Usage Notes and Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_nn.htm#SPATL1032) for more information. Data type is `NUMBER`. For example: `'sdo_num_res=5'`

So just set `sdo_num_res` to whatever number of results you want returned.